# combining list of list with addition of value when list items are missing

Tags: python, list

I need to combine list of lists and add items when items are not present in other lists.

I need a way to represent when a value is not present in a list across three list of lists.  In the example below `['e','f']` is only in list one (`l1`), so a placeholder would be added to list two (`l2`) and three (`l3`) to represent that it is in list one, but not list two and three.  The placeholder would be something like `['e','-']`.

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'],['e','f']]
l2 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]
l3 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]
```

So in the end, every list would have an entry for any list item that had a unique value in the first position of a list item.

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'],['c','-'],['e','f']
l2 = [['a', 'b'],['c','d'],['e','-']
l3 = [['a', 'b'],['c','d'],['e','-']
```

I tried converting the list of lists to sets and could find common objects, for example

```
l1_set = set(tuple(row) for row in l1)
l2_set = set(tuple(row) for row in l2)
l3_set = set(tuple(row) for row in l3)

print (ipl_set & vgda_set & odm_set)

set([('a', 'b')])
```

I am not sure how to manage the sets so I can find different values and modify the lists to include those different values, while keeping position in the list.

The order does matter.  I don't want to simply append missing list items like this:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'],['e','f'],['c','-']
l2 = [['a', 'b'],['c','d'],['e','-']
l3 = [['a', 'b'],['c','d'],['e','-']
```

Comment: Are your lists all sorted like this? Ie. in alphabetical order?

Comment: I had to obfuscate the real data, but yes, it can be consider in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

The function `add_missing_items()` accepts any number (`>0`) of lists and add to them items that are missing from other lists. Assumes that items inside the lists can be sorted alphabetically:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'],['e','f']]
l2 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]
l3 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]

def add_missing_items(*lists):
    l_sets = [set(tuple(row) for row in l) for l in lists]
    u = l_sets[0].union(*l_sets[1:])

    for lst, slst in zip(lists, l_sets):
        l = [list(v) for v in u.difference(slst)]
        for missing_value in l:
            missing_value[1::1] = '-' * (len(missing_value)-1)
        lst[:] = sorted(lst + l)

add_missing_items(l1, l2, l3)

print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

Prints:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', '-'], ['e', 'f']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', '-']]
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a couple in a list is in another list like this:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b'],['e','f']]
l2 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]
l3 = [['a', 'b'],['c', 'd']]

for couple in l1:
    if couple not in l2:
        print(couple)
```

In the case above, it's just an example to show how you can find elements that are different from `l1`. However, you can image modify an array instead of just make a print.

Hence, if you want to modify your arrays, I advise you to copy them and not modify directly original arrays.